# How to fix the LED backlight on my Dell laptop?

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair, laptop-display

I have a Dell Precision M3800 notebook that's served me well over the years. A few months ago I dropped it and ever since the display has had problems. The LCD itself is fine, but the LED backlight doesn't work for the right-most one-fifth of the display. There's a vertical dark strip down the right side of my screen. This makes it difficult to see task bar notifications, etc. Occasionally it will randomly fix itself for a few minutes and at other times, the entire right half of the backlight goes out.

I've done DC jack repair, replaced the battery and one of the fans. I'm comfortable doing surgery on this machine. However, I can't find any obviously loose or broken wires inside. Where should I be looking?

Comment: Probably inside the screen assembly itself. I'd give it up as a bad job & just buy a new screen

Answer (score 0):

Since you are comfortable working on the component level, open the display and look for a loose connector or a break in the PCB or in a soldered joint. Since it's intermittent, wiggle components *gently*, as well as the PCB, with a toothpick or plastic tool. Resolder an intermittent joint (under magnification, a poor joint often looks like a doughnut, with the lead in the center making loose contact with the edge).

You've lost nothing in trying, since you'd need to open the shell to replace the display, anyway. There are [instructions with videos](https://www.parts-people.com/blog/2017/02/10/dell-precision-m3800-p31f001-lcd-display-assembly-removal-and-installation/) online. **N.B.** There are a number of parts to remove and replace, so give yourself ample room and time in a [clean, well-lighted place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Clean,_Well-Lighted_Place). {with Ernest apologies}